# Homework - combinatorics cartesian plane

Tags: combinatorics

hopefully last combinatorics question for today...I can't handle this subject.

Ok here is an interesting question

Oria is standing at (0,0) and he needs to get to (a,b) $a,b >0$ a,b are integers.

In how many different ways can Oria get to (a,b) if oria can only walk 1 step to the right or 1 up (IE Oria can't move down or move left)

I've tried fooling around and crunching the numbers in hopes I could find some sort of equation or something familiar, but nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: You have $a+b$ steps to make. You need to choose which ones are going right and which ones are going up.
In how many way can you order $a$ white balls and $b$ black balls?

Comment: $\frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$ ?

Comment: @Oria: Yes, or more simply, $\binom{a+b}a$.

Comment: That's it I think